# React-native: unable to do live reload

Tags: react-native

I am unable to do live reload.

1. In "Dev Setting" I set my ipaddress 192.X.X.X:8081.
2. Then I modified my index.android.js
3. Shake my device
4. on popup menu, selected "Reaload JS"

I am getting error saying unble to connect to server. Run package manage etc.

Can some one point me to any vide or article about exact live reload?

Answer (score 2):

Did you run : `react-native start` ... 
If you haven't this server running locally, it will display on your screen `unble to connect to server` after reloading. 
Did you do  too the `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` sentence ? (sorry for not adding comm, I haven't enough reputation points to do this.